# Using DOMDocument to add elements in an HTML file in a specific position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

my php is :

```
  <?php 
         $Obj = $_POST['OGGETTO']; 
         $Descr = $_POST['DESCRIZIONE']; 


            $doc = new DOMDocument;
            $doc->loadHtmlFile("index.html");

            // Get the parent node where you want the insertion to occur
            $parent = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

            $after = "$$$$"; // i know it's wrong

            // Append (insert) the child to the parent node
            $parent->appendChild($after);
            // Save the resulting HTML
            echo $doc->saveHTML();      
     ?>
```

my HTML file (index.html)

```
 <body>
    ......
    ......
        <div class="one">

                [**NEW DIV HERE**]

        </div>
    </body>
```

What i want to accomplish is : my php script should add the following  tag in the previous [**NEW DIV HERE**] and save "index.html" file. but also the "[**OGGETTO**]" value should be replaced with "$Obj" and "[**DESCRIZIONE**]" with "$Derc"

DIV to put in he HTML file :

```
<div class="two">
        <div class="three">
            <a>
                <img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="next"> </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="#"><span>[**OGGETTO**]</span></a></h4>
        <p>[**DESCRIZIONE**]</p>
    </div>
```

So if $Obj is = "MENU" and $Desrc is = "this is a website", the final index.html file will be

```
<body>
       <div class="one">

          <div class="two">
            <div class="three">
                <a>
                    <img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span class="next"> </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <h4><a href="#"><span>MENU</span></a></h4>
            <p>this is a website</p>
        </div>

       </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you'd need to find your container `<span>`s and `<p>`s, extract the text node, update it, then save the modified dom. Or, if you can absolutely guarantee you'd never make an incorrect replacement, you can extract the complete html as a string, then do a simple `$html = str_replace('[**OGGETTO**], $new_content, $html)`

Comment: how i can find my container if it doesn't exist ? before i have to put the entaire DIV block in the "[**NEW DIV HERE**]" position (see above)

Comment: so i have to use  $str_put = "<div class='two'><div class='three'><a><img src=''images/pic2.jpg' /></a></div><h4><a href='#'><span>".$Obj."</span></a></h4><p>".$Descr."</p></div>"; using $str_put string and putting it in the HTML file , but how can i do it ?